# ios, healthkit observer query

Tags: ios, iphone, healthkit

I am writing an ios app with health kit integration. I want my application to be notified by health app whenever new **heart rate** data get saved in health app and that new data  fall behind lower limit or exceeds upper limit.

For example lower limit - > 50, upper limit -> 100, so

```
if(newHeartRateData<50 OR newHeartRateData>100)
```

then application needs to be notified.

I am using observer query for this but not getting clue how to insert predicate for lower and upper limit.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: a value can never be less than 50 and more than 100 the same time, so your condition will always be false.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter samples by their quantity value by using predicates returned from the [predicateForQuantitySamplesWithOperatorType:quantity:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/HKQuery/predicateForQuantitySamplesWithOperatorType:quantity:) method on `HKQuery`.